# How to set display the indentation symbol when wrapping a new line in Vim，when input it will disappear

Tags: vim, indentation, word-wrap

Does anyone knows how to set this？ Vim will display the indentation symbol when wrapping a new line， When input it will disappear.

[image]

Comment: Can you include text code in your question rather than a screenshot?

Comment: @tshimkus thanks for your reply, Not a code problem, I want to know how the symbol displayed on the line where the cursor is in the picture is how to set it, it shows the indentation, those symbols will disappear when you enter any character

Comment: Gotcha. It might be helpful to note which vim build you are using. The program has been around for over 25 years and has gone through many revisions in that time. If you don't find your answers here I found that there is a vi/vim stack exchange (currently in beta): https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These options will make sure trailing spaces are displayed as dots (or whichever other character you set instead). As you say, the dots disappear once another character is entered, as the spaces are then not trailing any more. Look through other listchars options as well, if you want to see e.g. tabs or other cool stuff.

```
set listchars=trail:·
set list
```

(See `:help 'listchars'`, `:help 'list'`)

Comment: thanks  maybe i know why i set this.but i cant see it in go file.becase i set another settings.